# Show that $\mathbb{M}$ is a probability measure and that under that measure the random variable $X$ has normal distribution $N(a,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

We define a measure $\mathbb{M}$ which is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mathbb{P}$, and has the Radon–Nikodym derivative $\mathbb{M}/\mathbb{P}$ = $^{−^{2}/2}$. I need to show that $\mathbb{M}$ is a probability measure and that under the measure $\mathbb{M}$ the random variable  has normal distribution
(,1). I tried to show that $\mathbb{M}(\Omega)=1$, with $\Omega$ the unvivers using the definition from the course :$\mathbb{M}(\Omega)=\int_{\Omega} d\mathbb{M}/d\mathbb{P}~d\mathbb{P}=\int_{\Omega} e^{aX-a^{2}/2} d\mathbb{P}$. But then it seems like I can work with the expectation (I don't know why) and make appear a $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. I don't know how to pass from $d\mathbb{P}$ to $dx$. Can I have some help please.

Comment: (1) What is $\mathbb P$?  (2) Isn't there a missing exponent $2$ in your R-N derivative formula?

Comment: It's not mentionned in the exercise but I guess it's a probability measure. Yes sorry, it's $e^{aX - a^{2}/2}$

Comment: @kimchilover sorry

Comment: I think I have it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\ X\ $ to be $\ \mathcal{N}(a,1)$-distributed with respect to $\ \mathbb{M}\ $, you must have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{M}\big(X\le x\big)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+ax-\frac{a^2}{2}}dx\\
&=\int_{X\le x}d\mathbb{M}\\
&=\int_{X\le x}e^{aX-\frac{a^2}{2}}d\mathbb{P}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^xe^{ax-\frac{a^2}{2}}dF_\mathbb{P}(x)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ F_\mathbb{P}\ $ is the distribution of $\ X\ $ with respect to $\ \mathbb{P}\ $.  For this to be true for all $\ x\ $, $\ F_\mathbb{P}\ $ *must be* the standard normal distribution.  If you make that assumption you should then be able to prove the required results (and it will be impossible to prove that $\ X\ $ is $\ \mathcal{N}(a,1)$-distributed with respect to $\ \mathbb{M}\ $ without that assumption).